# What is the difference between a precision timer and LinCMOS timer?

Tags: integrated-circuit, timer, 555

I'm busy with a certain project that needs a 555 timer chip. But there are different kind of timer chips and I don't know what the differences are.
What are the differences between a [precision timer](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/152184/Texas-Instruments-NE555P-Linear-IC-DIP8-Precision-timer?ref=searchDetail) and [LinCMOS timer](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/152197/Texas-Instruments-TLC555CP-Linear-IC-DIP8-LinCMOS-Timer?ref=searchDetail)?
I see that the U_CC voltage range is different, but what does this mean for the generated pulses.

Comment: Generally you should be sceptical of phrases like "precision" or "low power" or "high gain" on the first page of a datsheet. They might have some meaning relative to devices that were available prior to the one you're looking at. But once a newer better device comes out they don't go back and re-name the device as an "okay precision" or "not-too-high power" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Precision timer* is the original bipolar device, *LinCMOS timer* is a newer unipolar (CMOS) version.

In general, bipolar ICs are more rugged with higher VCC limits and strong push-pull outputs.

On the other hand, CMOS has much lower power consumtion and lower input currents.

For the 555 timer, the default choice is usually bipolar, unless you need low voltage (2 alkaline or 1 lithium coin cell) or low power consumption. Both types will give the same result.